# record collection detection and output amount of collisions

Tags: c#, silverlight, if-statement, for-loop, collision-detection

how would I go about and record the amount of collisions that happen ? I have a simple collision detection that will detect if a object collides with another now I wish to record them collisions.

**Code for collisions**

```
public void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        appleTimer += 1;
        if (appleTimer > 60)
        {
            appleTimer = 0;
            AddApple(new Apple());
        }

        for (int indx = 0; indx < myapples.Count; indx++)
        {
            myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);

            bool collided = DetectCollision(myapples[indx], myPig);
            if (collided)
            {
                // record how many apples are eaten here
                RemoveApple(myapples[indx]);
                indx--;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Before the loop `int count = 0;` and in place of your comment `count++;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to remove objects from a list while looping through the list, it is easier to loop backwards in order not to mess up the index:

```
    int eatenAppleCount = 0;
    for (int indx = myapples.Count - 1; indx >= 0; indx--) {
        myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);
        bool collided = DetectCollision(myapples[indx], myPig);
        if (collided) {
            eatenAppleCount++;
            RemoveApple(myapples[indx]);
        }
    }
```

Note: If `myapples` is a `List<Apple>` then you can remove an apple with

```
myapples.RemoveAt(indx);
```

If `myapples` is an array, replace it with a list. Arrays should only be used if their length does not change. Lists are dynamic "arrays" that can grow and shrink.